# Отключил диспетчер задач

Tags: windows-8, службы, диспетчер-задач

У меня возникла большая ошибка на компьютере. Недавно я сидел в службах пк (services.msc), и отключал не нужные службы. И, после того как я перезагрузил свой пк, и захотел зайти в диспетчер задач , у меня выдало такую ошибку -  [image: Ошибка диспетчера задач]

А когда я захотел зайти в "службы", выдало такую ошибку -
[image: Ошибка служб]

И когда хочешь что-то скачать, выдаёт такую ошибку - [image: ошибка при скачивании]

### Прошу, помогите! Я не знаю что делать, а делать сброс пк не хочу, много личных файлов, и нет флешки или что-то на подобие флешки, чтобы я туда всё перекачал.
Наверно, я отключил службу отвечающую за Диспетчер задач и Службы.

P.S

Ошибки текстом

```
Диспетчер задач -  (путь к файлу)
"Неопознанная ошибка."
```

Службы (services.msc) - C:\Windows\System32\services.msc

```
"Указанная служба не может быть запущена, так как отключена либо она сама, либо все связанные с ней устройства."
При попытке войти в "Управление компьютером", выдаёт такую ошибку - 
С:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3\03 - Computer Management.ink
"Неопознанная ошибка"
```

При попытке скачать какой-то файл, выдаёт такую ошибку -

```
"ShellExecuteEx: сбой; код 1058.
Указанная служба не может быть запущена, так как откючена либо она сама, либо все связанные с ней устройства."
```

И, в связи с этим, я не могу скачать альтернативу Диспетчера Задач, и включить все службы обратно.

Я не знаю какая именно служба отвечает за Диспетчер задач, службы, управ. компьютером и т.д, я просто всё по отключал

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, ошибки текстом (скрины можно оставить) так будет проще искать их в гугле, тем кто захочет помочь, и найти тем, у кого такая же проблема

Comment: @gil9red добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Попробуйте загрузить Windows в `Безопасном режиме с поддержкой командной строки`.
- В командной строке введите `services.msc`.
- У всех служб поставьте параметр запуска `Автоматически`.
- Перезагрузите компьютер (я перезагружал с помощью команды `shutdown /r`)

**P.S.** На виртуальной машине все работает.

Comment: Как запустить безопасный режим? при запуске компьютера я нажимаю `shift + F8`, но не работает.

Comment: [Здесь](http://winlined.ru/articles/zapusk_windows_8_v_bezopasnom_rezhime_safe_mode.php) показаны способы запуска безопасного режима.

Comment: Я попробую как нибудь позже, если не получится - буду делать полный сброс ноутбука. Я, к счастью, смог загрузить нужные файлы на гугл диск.

Comment: СПАСИБО!!! Получилось! Я включил все службы на автоматический режим, и сработало! ещё раз СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте команду `msconfig`. Должна сработать, так как вроде бы эта утилита не требует никаких служб как зависимостей. Далее выберите *обычный запуск*. И нажмите **OK**.

[image: msconfig in action]

Но если все же не поможет, загрузитесь в безопасный режим и попробуйте сделать это оттуда.

Comment: Не могу запустить. Я уже писал, в вопросе. Внимательно прочитайте, я там писал что она выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Как я понял, я отключил какую-то службу отвечающую за эти файлы и их прогрузку, и я не могу ничего изменить. Я кое что попробую, @SurfaceStack дал ссылку, где показано как сделать восстановление к определённой дате,  и я попробую сделать это.

Comment: @Anonim Про `msconfig` в вопросе нет ни слова.

Comment: Разве msconfig это не диспетчер задач? если нет, то прошу прощения.

Comment: @Anonim А вы на скриншоте видите диспетчер задач?

Comment: нет, не вижу. Но в любом случае, он не запустился.

Comment: Тогда как вариант, вы можете удалить файл реестра. Делайте это в безопасном режиме. И не забудьте забекапить его куда-нибудь. Снесение реестра приведет к восстановлению настроек по-умолчанию.

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: Тогда не удаление реестра, а восстановление его из копии, созданной Windows, лежащей по пути `C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack`
[Источник](https://www.windxp.com.ru/articles89.htm)

Comment: У меня там целых 5 файлов, выбрать `DEFAULT` ?